# Building a custom SDK library from Xcode, does it matter what I sign it with?

Tags: ios, xcode

If I'm building a custom library say CustomLib.a, does it matter what I use as a signing key to sign it with?  I'm asking this because I'm building this for customers, and I'm not sure why I need to sign this.

What if I sign with developer key? What about enterprise key, or distribution key?  Or not signing it at all?

Any one have the same experience?

Thanks

Comment: How are you going to "sign" the library ? I can't find anything related at [libtool man](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/libtool/), note `codesign` is called only against `.app` file. You can check the order  of the commands at Log Navigator of Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put: you don't sign it. After an app uses it, it will be statically linked to the binary of **that particular app,** and only that needs to be signed.